# RDi online help not working - does changing http to https fix it?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rational-developer-for-i

There has been recent discussion on [midrange.com](https://archive.midrange.com/wdsci-l/201704/msg00004.html) of RDi online help not working due to IBM switching access to the https protocol. Can this be fixed by Window > Preferences > Help > Content, then choose a remote help URL, Click Edit Change http to https, Click OK?

Comment: I am using RDi 9.5.0.3 and the mentioned url's work with http://. What version of RDi are you using?

Comment: RDi is made up of lots of plugins, so not sure which version number is RDi's version number. Remote System LPEX Editor Support plugin is 9.5.0.v20150615_0110 and RPG and COBOL Tools plugin is 9.5.0.v20150617_1818.

Comment: OK, I think I have found the RDi version number - feature "IBM Rational Developer for i" has version of 9.5.0.v20150824_0113

Comment: You are looking too hard. Go to Help -> About. The Version number is on the third line of the dialog, but your LPEX build number is earlier than mine so I suspect that you should upgrade RDi.

Comment: Thanks @jmarkmurphy.Third line down says Version 9.5, I'll talk to the guy who installed RDi about getting the latest version

Comment: You can't actually try this on your own?

Comment: Have tried: Help, Check for Updates gets "No updates were found" and Help, Check for Rational Developer for i Updates, return s message "Administrator privileges are required"

Comment: What puzzles me is that when clicking on help topics the message "Waiting for http://127.0.0.1.51900/help/advanced/content.jsp" can be seen and yet in Preferences,help,content there is no local help configured? as shown in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W5655eb35823a_4511_8970_3f665cc5d557/page/How%20to%20Use%20Local%20Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm on version 9.5.0 which seems to search for local help, I used this [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAE4W_9.5.0/com.ibm.help.common.remote.nolhu.doc/topics/t_configure_local_help.html) to install local help. This allows me to see help documents in RDi using Help, Help Contents but still takes a very long time to respond and display the page. As far as I can tell, there is no preference to disable local help.